# Extract data from h5 (nexus) file more efficiently than [()]

Tags: python, performance, hdf5, h5py

When reading image back from a 4GB .h5 nexus file via h5py like

```
meas = h5py.File(file, 'r')['entry1']['measurement']['mte']
im = meas[()]
```

the first line processes in 200µs, but the last takes 2200ms.

I suppose this is where it actually gets the images. `meas` are 21 2048x2048 monochromatic arrays.
Is there a way to read it faster or is it just because the images are so large?

I actually only need part of the images, is there a way to read only e.g. the first 100 rows to speed up the process?

edits:

`meas` is a `<HDF5 dataset "mte": shape (21, 2048, 2048), type "<f8">`
`[()]` turns it into a numpy array

`meas[:]` also takes 2200ms,
`np.array(meas)` takes 2700.

Any slicing applied to either method does not change anything in timing, i.e. `meas[:][0:100]` still takes 2200ms, as I would expect

Comment: As you note, the first just finds the dataset in the file's directory structure, the second does the heavy lifting.  The relevant section in the docs: https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data

Comment: The first line returns a h5py dataset object named `meas`. Dataset objects behave like NumPy arrays . You can use slice notation to read part of the dataset into an array. The first 100 rows would be `meas_slice = meas[0:100,:]`. I don't recognize `im_ref[()]`. Is it a nexus function?

Comment: it's hard to reproduce, those two lines are somehow connected to each other?

Comment: @kcw78, `h5py` models its "indexing" on `numpy`, but isn't exactly a subclass.  "An empty tuple (()) to retrieve all data or scalar data".  For arrays `[()]` selects an item from a 0d array.  Here it also applies to all of other datasets.  I believe earlier versions recommended `[:]` to fetch all.  Anyways, the speed is limited by the file read, not the indexing notation.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks. My question was about `im_ref` and not the indexing. I don't see how it is connected to the `meas` dataset object. Maybe just a typo?

Comment: Sorry, i made a typo when copying the code. Now it's more clear.  the second row is basically just `[()]` applied to the result from the first row.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for confirming/correcting.  `meas[()]`, `meas[:]`, and `np.array(meas)` all return a NumPy array. Not sure why the last method runs slower. You said you want the first 100 rows. How would you define the slice notation for `shape (21, 2048, 2048)`?

Comment: What is `meas[:][0:100]` supposed to be doing?  This isn't slicing the 2nd dimension.  For that you need `meas[:,0:100]`.  But I suspect that won't help with speed.  `meas[0:10]` might be faster, since it doesn't have to load all the dataset.  But slices on the 2nd dimension still require loading the whole set.